# What is _gali cookie and how to disable it?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, google-analytics

On my site, if user refuses to use cookies, I block tracking of Google Analytics using:

```
window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXXX-X'] = true;
```

And I delete cookies about Google Analytics (_ga, _gid, and _gat) using:

> Cookies.remove from js-cookie

Everything works so far.

However when I navigate on my site I saw a weird cookie: _gali. What's this ? How to disable it ?

Comment: See this for what it is: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-link-attribution#customizing_enhanced_link_attribution